# Postgres order entries by id, self reference id and date, after every parent, list childs

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, self-referencing-table

I have the table `orders` with the following fields `id`, `updated_at`, `self_ref_id`, and others which doesn't count.
The column `self_ref_id` is a self reference two an order, one order can have multiple children, a child will not have other children.
I am trying to order all entries by `updated_at desc` but after every parent order, I want to have his children, also ordered by `updated_at`, even though the child `updated_at` is lower than the next parent `updated_at`.

I tried to order them by `updated_at` and group them by `id` and `self_ref_id`.

I am using go with gorm, if it counts, but I need a hint how to make this query.
I was also trying with a subquery, but I didn't succeeded.
I don't need duplicate fields, I just want to order them.

I can do some post-processing to sort them how I want, but I am curious If I can do this from a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a self-join:

```
select o.*
from orders o
left join orders p on p.id = o.self_ref_id
order by 
    coalesce(p.updated_at, o.updated_at), 
    p.id is not null,
    o.updated_at
```

The `left join` brinds the parent row, if any. Then, we order by the parent date (or the current date if there is no parent); the second ordering criteria (`p.id is not null`) gives the priority to the "parent" row, and the last criteria orders children rows by date.

Comment: Thank you very much